# Django get data from two tables, related data only

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

Okay so I have a homepage that displays images. This is accessed from my images tables. It contains a column of the owner, in the form of a user id. I also have a table of users, who've submitted those images. How do I make it so that when displaying images, it uses the ID to get the username from the user table?

views.py:

```
def index(request):
    context = {}
    populateContext(request, context)
    context.update(gallery=ImageDoc.objects.only('thumbfile').order_by('-id'))

    return render(request, 'register/index.html', context)
```

So in the index.html page, I can iterate through 'gallery' to show the images. Like so:

```
{% for image in gallery %}
    <a href="/logo/{{ image.slug }}">
        <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ image.largethumbfile }}">
        {{ image.title }} by {{ image.username }} for {{ image.price }}
    </a>
{% endfor %}
```

"image.username" obviously doesn't work. I know I need to access the users table with this:

```
get_users = User.objects.get()
```

And reformat grabbing the images data to this:

```
get_images = ImageDoc.objects.get()
```

But I don't know the next step to ensure the data matches. Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: doens't {{ image.owner.username }} work?

Comment: Tried it, it didn't work.

Comment: If your model uses a foreign key to the owner you should be able to access it, but I don't usually use the context update route, I prefer using render_to_response and passing my queries through that. And you have to use the name of the foreign key on the {{ images.owner }}

Comment: Ah yes, it appears I have three tables. The images table is owned by the userprofile table, which in turn is owned by the user table. So I used this {{ image.user.user.username }} Worked! Thank you!

Comment: excellent! Glad to be of help!

Answer (score 0):

If the `Images` table has the `Users` table as a foreign key, then each `Images` object will have a `user_id` parameter. Therefore, if you have a value called `given_user_id` you can do something like:

```
Images.objects.get(user_id=given_user_id)
```

If you have a `username` instead of a `user_id`, you can do something like:

```
Images.objects.get(user=User.objects.get(username=username))
```

Unfortunately, you cannot perform queries inside of a template block. You'll need to do any querying before you pass in your context object to the render function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That should also work. But what about if I don't have the "username" variable to work with? In the index, I'm simply listing all of the images out, regardless of owner.

Comment: Well ideally each image should have a User object associated with it, right? You could potentially create a dict object which maps Images to Users/usernames and add it to the context object. Or, you could even try `image.user.username`, not sure if that'll work off the top of my head but give it a shot.